# how can i solve the problem with stack in C?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

i made Global Variables

```
struct node* top;
```

```
struct node {
    char x;
    struct node* next;
};
```

it is struct node

```
struct node* newnode(char x) {
    struct node* new1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new1->x = x;
    new1->next = NULL;
    return new1;
}
```

and i Initialized top=NULL;

ex) push(top, a)

```
void push(struct node* h, char c) {
    struct node* new1 = newnode(c);

    if (count(h) > N) {
        printf("Stack FULL\n");
        return;
    }
    new1->next = h;
    h= new1;

}
```

Then shouldn't the address value of top be the address value of new1 after the push function?

Even after the push function ends, the top remains NULL, so I don't know what to do.

Please give me some advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C Programming Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458472/c-programming-stack)

Comment: noo it isnt my answer

Comment: Huh? You can look in the other posts answers how they implement the push function.

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to know how to fix my codes, i think his codes are different with mine

Comment: note: `struct node {
    char x;
    struct node* next;
};` is a struct definition, NOT a variable declaration

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct node* new1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  1) in C, the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL), call `perror( "malloc failed" )`  to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: in the `push()` function, check `count()` before calling `newnode()` Otherwise the result is a heap memory allocation that is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  OR `if (count(h) > N) {
        printf("Stack FULL\n");  free( new1 );
        return;`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the *value* in `top`, so the function cannot change what is in `top`.  You can either pass a pointer to `top`, or have the function return the new value you want for `top` so that the caller can assign it to `top`.

Comment: do  you mean i need to make a pointer to pass to top?? thank you for answer

Comment: You could pass a pointer *to* `top`, which the function could use to change the contents of `top`.